# how to concat cells by comma using java

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file in which each cell is a number which may contain a comma. Now I like to import it into my program so that the cells are splitted. Is there any way to join the numbers correctly?

For example the following file content:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
10      10,000  100     1000
```

After splitting by comma it is listed:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
10       10     000      100     1000
```

while the excepted output would be:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 
10      10000   100     1000
```

Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("csv file");

try (BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

    while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if((i<5) || (i == myDimensionProcessor.rowCount-1))
        {  
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            String a = line.replaceAll("[/\\\\%|*^`]", "");
            c = a.replaceAll("--", "NA");                                                    
            i++;
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(c,",");

            while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                //get next token and store it in the array
                numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
                System.out.print(numbers[row][col]);
                col++;     
            }
            col = 0;
            System.out.println();
            row++;
        }
    }
```

Actually I am splitting the csv file value into an array, but the value used with comma should not be splitted. How can i do that?

Even though it is splitting the comma value into different columns, how can I append that splitted value into a single cell and then the remaining value should be automatically shifted into the columns before?

Comment: your CSV file's column  is having values with tab seperated, why are you spliting on the basis of comma .
and why are you iterating to null  instead of new line .

Comment: In CSV file, i have to split the value only by comma into an array... because it is a comma separator file... but in that CSV file i have a column values with comma in it. for example (10,000) I don't want to split this value, it should be in that corresponding cell only in that column. Likewise any comma values should not be splitted in CSV file. Only column to column values should be splitted into an array.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers with commas are in some kind of quotation marks you should first replace numbers like this "10,000" with 10000 and then do the tokenization. You can do it like this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("\"\\s*(\\d+),(\\d+)\\s*\"", "$1$2");
```

Or if you like to preserve the quotation marks:

```
line = line.replaceAll("(\")\\s*(\\d+),(\\d+)\\s*(\")", "$1$2$3$4");
```

You need to replace the \" in the code samples above with the appropriate quotation mark character.

If all your numbers in the csv are in quotation marks you can remove all commas in numbers like this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("(\\d+),(\\d+)", "$1$2");
line = line.replace("\"", "");
```

This will work if no csv delimiter comma is between two digits. When all your numbers are in quotation marks this is safe to assume. Use the second line if you also want to remove the quotation marks.

Comment: problem is the data are dynamic.... there may be one comma or two commas or three commas.... i want that value shouldn't be splitted in CSV file

Comment: if there is three commas in a value.... that statement is not working.... i want that statement should be dynamic...

Comment: i edited the answer. the last code sample might solve your problem. although i guess it's not the safest solution.

Comment: how can i solve this? 1,231.94      i want this number without any symbol 123194

Comment: how can i solve this number "1,231.94"? i want this number to be like this 1231.94 in single column.... this number shouldn,t be splitted to next column in csv file

Comment: Did you try the last code sample? This should solve your problem. It might help if you post an unedited line of your csv file as example.

Answer (score 0):

Csv is way more complicated to process correctly than it looks. You are not going to end up with a reliable solution using regular expressions, not to mention this is going to be extremely slow.

Just use a library dedicated for that, such as [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) and save yourself the headache. Here's a simple example:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial.
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(file));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: As [we discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34115974/3093387), please edit the disclaimer of your affiliation with univocity into all the answers you have promoting the uniVocity-parsers library.

Comment: Trying to do that. But the site allows me to edit only 5 answers per day.

Comment: Ah, OK. If you don't mind I'd be glad to edit them in for you. Would that be OK with you?

Answer (score 0):

If your column with commas in it is not quoted, then you'll need to extract out each field manually.

I ran into this issue at work the other day and here was my thought process.

1. You have 4 columns
2. Say the second column has commas

I formed a regex starting with groupings for each column, so 4 columns separated by comma and potential space would be

```
(),\s*(),\s*(),\s*()$
```

Then I filled in the groups with the data I wanted to match

```
(\d+),\s*(.+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)$
```

In this case you have normal numbers for every column except the second, and so the second group grabs any character it can find. There may be a better way to write that, and I certainly would like to know, but I was in a time-crunch when I figured it out. And to show it works, a [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vH6lR0/1).

And following the other answer here is the relevant Java code,

```
line = line.replaceAll("(\\d+),\\s*(.+),\\s*(\\d+),\\s*(\\d+)$", "$1$2$3$4");
```