# Skip empty lines while CSV parsing

Tags: java, csv

I'm currently working with pulling a CSV file from a URL and modifying it's entries. I'm currently using a StreamReader to read each line of the CSV and split it into an array, where I can modify each entry based on its position.

The CSV is generated from an e-form provider where a particular form entry is a Multi-Line field, where a user can add multiple notes. However, when a user enters a new note, they are separating each note by a line return.

CSV Example:

```
"FName","LName","Email","Note 1: some text

Note 2: some text"
```

Since my code is splitting each CSV entry by line, once it reaches these notes, it believes it to be a new CSV entry. This is causing my code that modifies the entries to not work since the element positions become incorrect. (CSV entries with empty or single line note fields work fine)

Any ideas on the best approach to take for this? I've tried adding code to replace carriage returns or to skip empty lines but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: This is not a  valid CSV file, is it possible for you to clean it ?

Comment: Can you post your Reader method with `.split()`

Comment: @Berger why not valid? It conforms to [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: Consider using a CSV-reading library like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html).

Comment: @RealSkeptic  , I couldn't believe a csv line had line breaks, I'll check the RFC deeper :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for first column value in a row is null or not. If it is null continue to read next line.

Comment: Then , the line "Note 2: some text"" would be considered valid, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CSV example you have provided is supposed to be just **one** entry in the CSV file (with the last field spanning over several different lines due to newline breaks), you could try something like this, using 2 loops.

1. Keep a variable for the current CSV record (of `String[]` type) `currentRecord` and a `recordList` (a List or an array) to keep all the CSV records.
2. Read a line of the CSV file
3. Split it into an array of strings using the comma as the delimiter. Keep this array in a temporary variable.
4. If the size of this array is 1, append this string to the last element (4th) in `currentRecord` (if `currentRecord` is not null).
5. Keep reading lines off the CSV file, and repeating step 4 until the array size is 4.
6. If the size is 4, then this indicates that the record is the next record in the CSV file and you can add the `currentRecord` to `recordList`
7. Keep repeating steps 2 to 6 until you reach the end of the CSV file

It would be better if you can remove the line breaks in the field and clean the CSV file before parsing it though. It'll make things much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper CSV library to handle the writing and parsing. There's a few edge cases to handle here, not only the new line. Users could also insert commas or quotes in their notes and it will become very messy to handle this by yourself.

Try [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as it can handle all sorts of situations when parsing and writing CSV.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).